# airflow: task is marked as success inspite of process failed

Tags: airflow

I have the following logs of the airflow

```
[2023-04-20, 17:38:01 UTC] {local_task_job.py:272} WARNING - State of this instance has been externally set to failed. Terminating instance.
[2023-04-20, 17:38:01 UTC] {process_utils.py:129} INFO - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to group 3178305. PIDs of all processes in the group: [3178305]
[2023-04-20, 17:38:01 UTC] {process_utils.py:84} INFO - Sending the signal Signals.SIGTERM to group 3178305
[2023-04-20, 17:38:01 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1479} ERROR - Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses.
[2023-04-20, 17:38:01 UTC] {connection.py:433} INFO - closed
[2023-04-20, 17:38:02 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:137} INFO - Task received SIGTERM signal
[2023-04-20, 17:38:02 UTC] {python.py:177} INFO - Done. Returned value was: None
[2023-04-20, 17:38:02 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1318} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=test, task_id=tasktest, execution_date=20230420T135457, start_date=20230420T171435, end_date=20230420T173802
[2023-04-20, 17:38:02 UTC] {process_utils.py:79} INFO - Process psutil.Process(pid=3178305, status='terminated', exitcode=0, started='17:14:34') (3178305) terminated with exit code 0
```

we can see

```
[2023-04-20, 17:38:01 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1479} ERROR - Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses.
```

that means task has failed

but its says

```
[2023-04-20, 17:38:01 UTC] {connection.py:433} INFO - closed
[2023-04-20, 17:38:02 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:137} INFO - Task received SIGTERM signal
[2023-04-20, 17:38:02 UTC] {python.py:177} INFO - Done. Returned value was: None
[2023-04-20, 17:38:02 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1318} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS.
```

how to catch this and mark task as failure.

Comment: Could you show the task description? I have seen a similar issue where we were using Bash Operator to run something like `statement1; statement2;` and if statement1 failed and statement2 succeeded task was marked as successful. We replaced `;` with `&&` to stop as soon as something failed.

Comment: Its a PythonOperator

Comment: After `SIGTERM` your logs say `{python.py:177} INFO - Done. Returned value was: None`. Possibly related to error handling in your Python code. Make sure to raise an exception again if you are handling it in your code.